# How to display in the logs the select query within the shell?

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix

i have this shell script below.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
#

FNC_DIR=/test/Create_User
PWD_DIR=/test/users

. ${FNC_DIR}/db.profile

csrpass=`cat ${PWD_DIR}/csradmin.user`

/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/bin/sqlplus /nolog << EOF > /test/Log/user_create.log

conn csradmin/${csrpass}@PNDBCSR2
select * from global_name;

echo "select
   dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', username) || '/' usercreate
from
   dba_users where username = 'NSAGUN'";




exit;

EOF
```

But I got errors in the log.

SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "echo "sele..." - rest of line ignored.
0734: unknown command beginning "dbms_metad..." - rest of line ignored.
0042: unknown command "from" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "dba_users ..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.

I just want to show in the log (/test/Log/user_create.log) the result of my query.

```
select
       dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', username) || '/' usercreate
    from
       dba_users where username = 'NSAGUN'";
```

How can I do this?

UPDATE

I use the code provided below and I got this in the log:

```
SQL>
SQL> select
  2     dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', username) || '/' usercreate
  3  from
  4     dba_users where username = 'NSAGUN';


   CREATE USER "NSAGUN" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '1EE5F5XXXXXB194'

      DEFAULT T



SQL>
SQL> spool off
```

I just want to display the create statement part and it seems that it is incomplete in the log. I am expecting just this in the log file.

```
CREATE USER "NSAGUN" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '1EE5F58CB716B194'
      DEFAULT TABLESPACE "PIN01"
      TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "PINTEMP"
 /
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is a shell command, but you are trying to use it within an Oracle SQL script.

The Oracle SQL equivalent is `spool`. You also need to set some additional parameters to control the output correctly (i.e. not printing to screen, not echoing the actual commands, line size, page size, etc...). For instance:

```
/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF

conn csradmin/${csrpass}@PNDBCSR2
select * from global_name;

set echo off
set termout off
set feedback off
set linesize 80    <<< use a greater value if output lines are truncated
set pagesize 0
set newpage 0
spool /test/Log/user_create.log create

select
   dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', username) || '/' usercreate
from
   dba_users where username = 'NSAGUN';

spool off

EOF
```

Comment: Can't really help more at the moment, don't have access to an Oracle system. However, 1) the output looks truncated (try setting `set linesize 300` or an event greater value; 2) I have a vague recollection that `set echo off` only works in scripts, and not when providing commands7 from standard input - in that case, use `sqlplus -s /nolog`.

Comment: the -s do the trick. thanks. :) and was able to display the whole result by adding: set longchunk 10000. thanks